# Are elements stored in struct are next each other

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

if i have a struct , say:

```
struct A {
int a,b,c,d,e;
}
A m;//struct if 5 ints
int n[5];//array of 5 ints.
```

i know that elements in the array are stored one after other so we can use *(n+i) or n[i]
But in case of struct ,is each element is stored next to each other (in the struct A)?

Comment: Please read all the answers carefully.

Comment: @juanchopanza it was the first bold answer. i forgot to accept the best answer. but now i have corrected it.

Comment: @Fennekin You have not accepted the best answer. It seems to me that you want the answer to be that members are adjacent. And so you are happy to accept an answer that says so. However, it is not the case that members must be adjacent. Why ask the question if you've already decided what the answer is?

Comment: @David Heffernan i wanted to know whether is this guaranteed or not. also this is the main reason I made those words bold while editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structs members in general are stored in increasing addresses but they **are not guaranteed** to be contiguous.so elements may not always be contiguous. In the example above, given $base is the base address of the struct the layout will be the following.

1. a will be stored at $base+0
2. b will be stored at $base+4
3. c will be stored at $base+8 ... etc

You can see the typical alignment values at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86

Comment: However +4,+8 will work only for type containing 4 bytes. eg int,float

Comment: Indeed, different types have different alignment paddings, and there are packing pragmas that can be used.

Comment: It's perfectly possible that a compiler will lay out this struct differently.

Comment: Differently regarding the padding, maybe, differently regarding the order, not so. But again, padding can be deduced from the arch/type combination, so as a principle the above holds.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler may insert padding as it wishes, except before the first item.

In C++03 you were guaranteed increasing addresses of items between access specifiers.

I'm not sure if the access specifier restriction is still there in C++11.

Comment: C++11 changes the wording a little, so adding a (vacuous) `public:` access specifier between members that are already public doesn't allow rearrangement. Basic idea's the same though.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that is granted is that members are stored in the same order.
Between elements there can be some "padding" the compiler may insert so that each value is aligned with the processor word length.

Different compiler can make different choices also depending on the target platform and can be forced to keep a given alignment by option switches or pragma-s.

Your particular case is "luky" for the most of compiler since `int` is normally implemented as "the integral that better fits the integer arithmetic of the processor". With this idea, a sequence of `int`-s is aligned by definition. But that may not be the case, for example if you have

```
struct test
{
   char a;
   short b;
   long c;
   long long d;
};
```

You can dscovery that `(&a)+1 != &b` and `(&b)+1 != &c` or `(&b)-1 != &a` etc.
What is granted is the progression `&a < &b; &b < &c; &c < &d;`

Answer (score -1):

I have written simple program to show strut elements are *next to each other*

```
int main() {

    struct S {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    };

    S s = {1,2,3};

    int* p = reinterpret_cast <int *> (&s);

    cout<<p[0]<<" "<<p[1]<<" "<<p[2];

    return 0;
}
```

> Output : 1,2,3

Remember, [] or *(i+1) are symantic construct, that suits with pointers, not with struct variables directly.

As suggested in *Cheers and hth. - Alf*'s answer, there can be padding, before or after struct elements.

Comment: This shows that your compiler, with your options stores the members of that struct adjacent. What about my compiler? And different structs?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Now that is surprised to me, I always read/knows that struct element are adjustment. Till now I have used Visual Studio, gcc, turbo C, all responds well to my belief.

Comment: if different types of elements are used then?

Comment: You cannot answer this question this way. It can only be answered by reference to the standard.

Comment: @Fennekin Still they are next to each other, just occupy different sizes.

Comment: is this compulsory, i mean is this **always** happens?

Comment: @Fennekin Have you seen any exception. I have never seen it. If yes, please update your question or paste link.

Comment: @Fennekin Why are you asking Pranit. He doesn't know the answer. That is clear by the way he attempted to answer. Where is the citation needed?

Comment: All your code does is invoke *undefined behaviour*. Search for "strict aliasing rule".